# Cast error when trying to check a condition in mongoose updateOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to set a field called `isFullCapacity` in my document using updateOne, with upsert set to true with this code -

```
 var temp = await Slot.updateOne(
          { branch: branchId, timeSlot: timeSlot, date: dates[i] },
          {     
            $addToSet: {
              timeRecords: createdTimeRecords[i],
          
            },
             $set: {
               isFullCapacity: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $gte: [
                      { $size: { $ifNull: ["$classRecords", []] } },
                      timeSlot.maxStudents,
                    ],
                  },
       then: true,
                  else: false,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          },

          { upsert: true }
        );
```

in this code, i am trying to set the isFullCapacity field of one `Slot` document to true if the `timeRecords` array's length, which is an array of objectIds field in the `Slot` Document, is equal to the timeSlot.maxCustomers value. The timeSlot is a destructured object which i am getting through the req.body and also contains the `maxCustomers` property.

When i run this code, it shows this error -

```
         "name": "CastError",
            "message": "Cast to boolean failed for value \"{ '$cond': { if: { '$gte': [Array] } } }\" (type Object) at path \"undefined\""
        },
        "name": "CastError",
        "message": "Cast to Boolean failed for value \"{ '$cond': { if: { '$gte': [Array] } } }\" (type Object) at path \"isFullCapacity\" because of \"CastError\""
```

I have tried to check if the timeRecords is null as such, which was suggested by chatgpt, but the issue still persisted -

```
  { $size: { $ifNull: ["$timeRecords", []] } },
```

this is the `Schema` -

```
const Slot = Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    index: { order: 1 },
  },
  isFullCapacity: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  timeSlot: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  },
  branch: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Branch",
    required: true,
  },

  timeRecords: {
    type: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "timeRecords",
      },
    ],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Slot", Slot);
```

to recap the requirement, the `isFullCapacity` field of the `Slot` document should be set to `true` if the `timeRecords.length` of the `Slot` document is equal to the `timeSlot.maxCustomers`.

Comment: `{$eq:[...]}` is an aggregation operator.  You will need to use the pipeline form of update

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post the schema so it'd be better to understand your problem like what exact type of data you're expecting

`CastError` usually means the value you enter isn't the type mognoose expect eg if `id:a3ndtn6` and you give `mongoose id: an3ntn6$`

here the specialCase character isn't the type mongoose expecting.
so mongoose will throw the error with ErrorCode `11000` by default

Comment: Hi Sameer, thanks for the reply, I have added the Schema of the Slot model, the issue causing field is the `timeRecords` field, which is an array of objectIds corresponding to the `TimeRecord` model, the `isFullCapacity` field should be set to true if the `timeRecords` field length is greater than the `timeSlot.maxCustomers`. Also wanted to point out, we are adding newly created `TimeRecords` within the `updateOne` function, would we be able to achieve the functionality using the $set?